# Translate hintText with using easy_localization

Tags: flutter, localization

```
hintText?.tr()
```

I can't use this in hintText , it recommend to me to delete parantheses from there , but in documentation of easy_localization I can use this method

Answer (score 0):

`hintText` is nullable, so you are getting an error. You have to have a non-nullable `String` so use `(hintText ?? '').tr()`

Comment: Nope again same error , => "The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked"

Comment: @SametDemirtop please provide more code, so we could better understand the problem.